# How to achieve exception chaining in Dart?

Tags: dart, exception

In Java, I can achieve exception chaining by passing another exception to the new exception like this:

```java
try {
  doSomething();
} catch (Exception1 ex) {
  throw new Exception2("Got exception1 while doing the thing", ex);
}
```

I would like to achieve a similar result in Dart. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried that?  It looks like it would do as you ask.

Comment: Dart does not do exception chaining.  If explicit chaining is acceptable, then you could simply maintain a `List` of `Exception`s yourself whenever you throw a new exception from within an exception handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```dart
void main(){
  try {
    try {
      throw 'exception 1';
    } catch (e) {
      throw LinkedException('exception 2',e);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw LinkedException('exception 3',e);
  }
}

class LinkedException implements Exception {
  final String cause;
  final exception;

  LinkedException(this.cause,[this.exception]);

  @override
  String toString() => '$cause <- $exception';
}
```

If you catch the third exception and print it, you would get something like this:

```
exception 3 <- exception 2 <- exception 1
```

Dartpad Runnable example: https://dartpad.dev/4000ed0f1e170615923f6c1e7f5f468a

Comment: Exception chaining is keeping track of the previous exception when throwing a new exception from an exception handler.

Comment: Should have known better. my edited answer should be correct.